# java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method queryForList() on null object

Tags: java, unit-testing, grails, spring-jdbc

I have a simple getEmployeeList method in Service class which queries the database by using Spring JDBC to get the the list of employees.

```
class EmployeeListService
{

private static final String QUERY_FOR_GETTING_ALL_EMPLOYEE_LIST="select ID, name from emp order by name";

     def dataSource
      private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate

     @PostConstruct
     def init() {
           jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource)
     }


    def getEmployeeList()  {

        ArrayList<String> employeeList = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(QUERY_FOR_GETTING_ALL_EMPLOYEE_LIST);
        return employeeList;
    }
}
```

I am writing a Grails unit test for Null checking of getEmployeeList method.

```
    @WithGMock
class EmployeeListServiceTest  extends GrailsUnitTestCase {

    EmployeeListService empService;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        empService = new EmployeeListService();

    }

    @Test
    public void toCheckgetEmployeeListDoesNotReturnNull()
    {
        ArrayList<String> employeeList = empService.getEmployeeList()

        assertNotNull(employeeList);
    }
}
```

I get the list of employees when i execute the program in normal flow. But when i am executing the Unit test, I get below exception

```
 Failure:  toCheckgetEmployeeListDoesNotReturnNull(com.employee.home.service.EmployeeListServiceTest)

  java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method queryForList() on null object
       at com.employee.home.service.EmployeeListService.getEmployeeList(EmployeeListService.groovy:170)
       at com.employee.home.service.EmployeeListServiceTest.toCheckgetEmployeeListDoesNotReturnNull(EmployeeListServiceTest.groovy:24)
```

Comment: So, your jdbcTemplate is null.

Comment: it simply means jdbcTemplate is null. this is dependency problem! where you are creating jdbcTemplate object?

Comment: Though I have not mentioned jdbcTemplate and datasource, In actual I have created them in the service class i.e. EmployeeListService, Ideally it should not return null

Comment: I have added the missing code above.

Answer (score 0):

When during unit tests, you manually create an instance of your service in setUp method, the postConstruct method will not get called.

So following is not being called.

```
 @PostConstruct
     def init() {
           jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource)
     }
```

That results in your JdbcTemplate being null during unit tests.

I would suggest you use integration test if you need to test the database queries etc.